How to link to main site from meta
I don't see any visible link from the meta to go to the Quant SE. I have to directly type them in the browser's address bar.

There is a "main" link in the toolbar at the top. It's to the left of the search bar, next to "about" and "faq".

Duh, I was looking at the navbar below it. Thanks Chris.
